# HTML5 Desktop/Mobile Blog - jQuery UI or jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, layout, jquery-mobile, blogs

Ok, so I have been looking at getting back into game development. And been trying to keep a small blog. Been wanting somewhere to put up some tutorials of the things I work on apart from my schoolwork. I have been using blogger, but I have been getting back into scripting and web development and wanted to try to move off and just create something minimal of my own on my server. I am hooked on HTML5 and have been loving using jQuery for the simplicity it provides in my scripting. However I am still new to web development in general as most of what I have been doing in school deals strictly in native programming.

I have been trying to compare the jQuery UI library and jQuery Mobile. I am interested in creating my own blog from scratch. Nothing fancy. Just a place to post tutorials and such. I am sure I am up to the challenge. As I understand it though, jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile are two very completely different things. Other than that, and the fact that I like the theme I was able to make for jQuery UI on the themeroller app I am not too sure.

I want my blog to look good and run quickly on phones/tablets. Even on the desktop it will be very minimal. **Would it be easy to create a blog using jQuery UI and be able to easily scale it for mobile devices?** Or would it be better just to stick with jQuery mobile for both phones/tablets as well as for desktops since I am wanting minimal anyway? **Can I achieve anywhere near the customization and programmability with jQuery Mobile as I can with jQuery UI?**

If anyone knows any good solutions that will allow me to scale the same layout for both desktop and mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile have theme customization actually.

jQuery UI - http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
  jQuery Mobile - http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php

As far as versitility goes, it's really up to you, the mobile browsers are capable of running both jQuery UI and Mobile, so whichever you feel compfortable with and like on the desktop as well.

Now to address the layout sizing issue:

The easiest way to scale the same layout for desktop and mobile is to use liquid layouts with widths in percentages. However, to the mobile size it starts to skew rather quickly.

Rather than use just percentages, I would suggest using media queries. This will allow you to change the CSS as the screen size changes, and the syntax is very straight forward and easy to use.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  .class {
   background: #333;
  }
}
```

As long as that is at the bottom of your CSS document, that will overwrite any preexisting styles. What that is saying, is apply this style when the screen size is between 600 and 900 pixels. Meaning to test it you can actually scale the size of your browser to see the difference.

More on Media Queries : http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

TL;DR
 jQuery UI and Mobile are Themable so whichever you like
 Use Media Queries as well

Comment: This seems like a good route to take. And so as I understand it, this will override and so I could even attempt to place this into my current blogger xml template in order to scale that as well?

Comment: Media queries are a CSS attribute, so as long as you work them in on that end, then yes. You could even rewrite the CSS rule completely in the media queries if you wanted.